# Minimal volume of a tetrahedral

Tags: geometry, optimization

I'm unsure how to solve the following problem:

Let $\textbf{p}=(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ with $a,b,c > 0$. For $\alpha , \beta > 0$ the equation $$\alpha (x-a)+ \beta(y-b) + (z-c) =0$$ defines a plane which contains $\textbf{p}$. Together with the xy-plane, xz-plane and yz-plane this defines an irregular tetrahedral $$T:=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R} : x>0, y>0, z>0, z<c-\alpha(x-a)-\beta(y-b)\}$$ Find the pair $(\alpha, \beta)$ for which T has minimum Volume.

I'm aware of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/708261/find-out-minimize-volume-v-of-tetrahedral) similar problem but the definition of my tetrahedral and plane are different so im not sure what to do. Is $V_{tet}=\frac{1}{6}a  b  c$ or do I integrate or..?

All help is appreciated. Studying for my physics exam and am finding it hard to concentrate on my other homework. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

The intersection points of the given plane with the coordinate lines are $$\left(\frac{a\alpha+b\beta+c}{\alpha},0,0\right),\left(0,\frac{a\alpha+b\beta+c}{\beta},0\right), \left(0,0,a\alpha+b\beta+c\right). $$ Thus, the volume of the tetrahedral  is

$$V=\frac16 \frac{(a\alpha+b\beta+c)^3}{\alpha\beta},$$

which is the function to minimize.

Comment: You mean coordinate lines, not planes.

Comment: thanks! and shouldn't the y-intersect be $\left(0,\frac{\alpha a +\beta b + c}{\beta},0 \right)$?

Comment: @studious You are right. Typos fixed.

Comment: Nice answer! Easy and clear...